# Cast Datetime offset to Date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the date column in datetimeoffset format.

```
2016-01-09 05:49:06.3744350 +00:00
```

I want to convert it to only date format, e.g. `2016-01-09`.
I was able to convert datetimeoffset to datetime2 with this query.

```
convert(datetime2, sampleDate, 1)  as date
```

Would be much obliged if I could know how to convert this to the desired format in MS SQL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET, '2016-01-09 05:49:06.3744350 +00:00'))
```

Returns:

```
2016-01-09
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use CAST function

```
SELECT CAST('2016-01-09 05:49:06.3744350 +00:00' as date)
```